# Rails Feature Tests Failing in Rails 5.0 Upgrade

Tags: rspec, ruby-on-rails-5, capybara

I'm upgrading a rails app from 4.2 to 5.0. We are using `ruby 2.6.4`

My feature tests ran fine in `4.2`, but are failing now in `5.0`.   I have not been able to find anything about this using Google.  It seems to me as if the feature tests are not seeing the page.

```
Gemfile:
group :test do                                                                  
   gem 'factory_girl'                                                            
   gem 'factory_girl_rails'                                                      
   gem 'capybara'                                                                
   gem 'faker'                                                                   
   gem 'mocha', require: false                                                   
   gem 'webmock', require: false                                                 
   gem 'simplecov'                                                               
   gem 'rails-controller-testing'                                                
end
```

Gemfile.lock shows `capybara (3.32.1)`  I've played with a few different versions of capybara, but I get the same results.

Feature test:

```
require 'spec_helper.rb'

RSpec.feature "Manage Account Codes" do

  scenario "User creates a new Account Code" do
    # go to the new account code form
    visit new_admins_kuali_account_code_path

    # should be success
    expect(page.status_code).to eq(200)

    # are we on the right page/form?
    expect(page).to have_content("Use this form to add a new account code")
  end
  ...
end
```

Failure:

```
Manage Account Codes
  User creates a new Account Code (FAILED - 1)

Failures:

  1) Manage Account Codes User creates a new Account Code
     Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_content("Use this form to create a new account code")
       expected to find text "Use this form to create a new account code" in "Kuali Account Codes\n| | \"kuali_account_codes\", :action => \"index\") %> | | | | 'layouts/statlerwire' %>"
     # ./spec/features/kuali_account_code_spec.rb:19:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 1.45 seconds (files took 2.7 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/features/kuali_account_code_spec.rb:11 # Manage Account Codes User creates a new Account Code
```

The first test: `expect(page.status_code).to eq(200)` passes. I comment out the others so only it runs.  It seems like it gets to `page`, but it doesn't see/find anything else on the page.  Am I missing a needed gem for `rails 5.0`?

As mentioned, all feature tests passed in `4.0`.  Curious!

Thanks for any help.

-johnC

Comment: Try changing `require spec_helper` to `require rails_helper` in your spec file.

Comment: hashrocket, thank you for your post.   That was not the issue.  See my answer I posted.  I appreciate you looking at this problem, though.  Cheers!  Stay safe.

Comment: From the content of the error page it looks like you probably have an error details displaying gem (`better_errors`, etc) installed in your test environment.  You should check your Gemfile and make sure any gems like that are only in the `development` environment - later Rails fixed that default.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to fix this issue.  It ended up being caused by some CSS entry that "we believe" was added to deal with an older version of Internet Explorer.  When I tried to view the page/form the spec tests were for (on my development site), I was getting a few odd error messages.  In the mix of them was a syntax error on a css file:  `... found ; expecting }` I came across this:

From the css file:

```
table.display thead th {                                                        
   padding: 3px 10px;                                                            
   border-bottom: 1px solid black;                                               
   font-weight: bold;                                                            
   cursor: pointer;                                                              
   * cursor: hand;                                                                                                                                
}
```

The asterisk `*` was the bug.  A commit message from 2011 noted it was for `* property: set the value in IE < 7`. Removing it solved the problem.  The app I'm on is not a public app and we do not use/support older versions of IE, so removing it was not an issue.

It is a bit odd this was not a problem in previous rails versions, but 5.0 did not like it.

All feature tests passed.